# Javascript click counter not going beyond 1

Tags: javascript

I have some very basic javascript that is *supposed* to show how many times a link has been clicked and on the 5th click re-direct to a new page. It looks like this:

```js
function counter() {
  var counterCount = 0;
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
  counterCount += 1;
  amount.innerHTML = counterCount;
  if (counter === 5) {
   document.location.replace('https://developer.mozilla.org');
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="counter()" href="#">I need to be clicked 5 times before I redirect</a>

<p id="amount"></p>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

1. Why is my counter not going beyond 1?
2. Why isn't the re-direct working?

Comment: You reset the counter to zero every time the function is called. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: counterCount is created only in the local context of the function, and as soon as function execution ends, counter is erased. There are a few ways to get around this, the easiest is to define counterCount outside the scope of the function. If you want an even more advanced model, look up "stack frames".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because every time you click, you are re-initializing your variable back to 0.

To fix it, simply move your variable outside.

```
var counterCount = 0;

function counter() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    counterCount += 1;
    amount.innerHTML = counterCount;
    if (counterCount === 5) {
        document.location.replace('https://developer.mozilla.org');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call your function `counter()` you state that `var counterCount = 0;`

You can fix this to place your variable outside of the function:

```
var counterCount = 0;

function counter() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    counterCount += 1;
    amount.innerHTML = counterCount;
    if (counter === 5) {
        document.location.replace('https://developer.mozilla.org');
    }
}
```

```js
var counterCount = 0;

function counter() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    counterCount += 1;
    amount.innerHTML = counterCount;
    if (counter === 5) {
        document.location.replace('https://developer.mozilla.org');
    }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="counter()" href="#">I need to be clicked 5 times before I redirect</a>

<p id="amount"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You reset the counter to zero every time you call the function since this line is within it `var counterCount = 0;`. Move it outside the function.

```js
var counterCount = 0;

function counter() {
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
  counterCount += 1;
  amount.innerHTML = counterCount;
  if (counter === 5) {
    document.location.replace('https://developer.mozilla.org');
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="counter()" href="#">I need to be clicked 5 times before I redirect</a>

<p id="amount"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you are setting the counter to 0 every time you run the function. That's Why it only goes to 1. You have to define the counter-variable outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function counter() {
  const el =  document.getElementById("amount"); // Get the element
  const amount = el.innerHTML + 1; // Get the elements current value + 1
  el.innerHTML = amount; // Change elements value
  if (amount === 5) { // If the value is 5, redirect. This didnt work because your value never got to 5
    document.location.replace('https://developer.mozilla.org');
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="counter()" href="#">I need to be clicked 5 times before I 
redirect</a>

<p id="amount">0</p>
```

edit: Chin Leung's answer is actually better

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're defining the counterCount variable inside the counter function, every time you called that function the variable was reinitialized

```js
var counterCount = 0;
function counter() {
  
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
  counterCount += 1;
  amount.innerHTML = counterCount;
  if (counterCount === 5) {
   document.location.replace('https://developer.mozilla.org');
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="counter()" href="#">I need to be clicked 5 times before I redirect</a>

<p id="amount"></p>
```